# PHP: How can I grab a single file from a directory without scanning entire directory?

Tags: php, file, directory

I have a directory with 1.3 Million files that I need to move into a database. I just need to grab a single filename from the directory WITHOUT scanning the whole directory. It does not matter which file I grab as I will delete it when I am done with it and then move on to the next. Is this possible? All the examples I can find seem to scan the whole directory listing into an array. I only need to grab one at a time for processing... not 1.3 Million every time.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I doubt he cares about the filename. He wants to grab any file, put it in the database, and move to the next one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<?php
$h = opendir('./'); //Open the current directory
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($h))) {
    if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..') { //Skips over . and ..
        echo $entry; //Do whatever you need to do with the file
        break; //Exit the loop so no more files are read
    }
}
?>
```

***[readdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)***

> Returns the name of the next entry in the directory. The entries are returned in the order in which they are stored by the filesystem.

Comment: I'd rather insert '.'and '..' in the database than do the check 1.3M times.

Comment: @SamyDindane, That check won't take long at all, especially compared to reading the file from disk and storing it in a database...

Comment: Still, the overhead could be avoided (every little helps) by simply running two calls to `readdir` before the loop, as `.` and `..` are always the first entries.

Comment: @Zombaya Indeed, it takes no time. I tried on my computer: took 200ms to run `if ($entry != '.' && $entry != '..') {}` 1.3M times. Surprising.

Comment: This code has a big problem if a directory entry is unwanted, like another directory or a symlink etc. - [better use the standard directory iterator which provides splfileinfo objects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10651943/367456).

Answer (score 5):

Just obtain the directories iterator and look for the first entry that is a file:

```
foreach(new DirectoryIterator('.') as $file)
{
    if ($file->isFile()) {
        echo $file, "\n";
        break;
    }        
}
```

This also ensures that your code is executed on some other file-system behaviour than the one you expect.

See [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/DirectoryIterator) and [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/SplFileInfo).

Comment: Doesn't this load the entire directory contents into an array though? That is what the Kyle is trying to avoid. That could make a difference when you have thousands of files in the folder.

Comment: @skibulk: No it does not, it iterates over the **DirectoryIterator** which is not an array but an object. This effectively prevents what you fear: an array.

Comment: Cool. I'm used to `foreach`ing arrays. So when `foreach` accesses the next index of the `DirectoryIterator`, it's actually invoking a method (IE getNextFile()) instead? Strange.

Comment: @skibulk: Yes, you could think about it in such a way. More precisely it invokes [`DirectoryIterator::next()`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.next.php), this is per contract in PHP between `foreach` and the [**Iterator** interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php). More clear?

Answer (score 2):

[readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) will do the trick. Check the exampl on that page but instead of doing the readdir call in the loop, just do it once. You'll get the first file in the directory.

Note: you might get ".", "..", and other similar responses depending on the server, so you might want to at least loop until you get a valid file.

Answer (score 0):

do you want return first directory OR first file? both? use this:

create function "pickfirst" with 2 argument (address and mode dir or file?)

```
function pickfirst($address,$file) { // $file=false >> pick first dir , $file=true >> pick first file
$h = opendir($address);

     while (false !== ($entry = readdir($h))) {

          if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..' && ( ($file==false && !is_file($address.$entry)) || ($file==true && is_file($address.$entry)) )  )
          { return $entry; break; } 

} // end while
} // end function
```

if you want pick first directory in your address set `$file` to false and if you want pick first file in your address set `$file` to true.

good luck :)