# Is there an efficient one-liner to grab the first file in a directory?

Tags: php, file, directory

I want to grab the first file in a directory, without touching/grabbing all the other files. The filename is unknown.

One very short way could be this, using `glob`:

```
$file = array_slice(glob('/directory/*.jpg'), 0, 1);
```

But if there are a lot of files in that directory, there will be some overhead.

Other ways are answers to this question - but all involve a loop and are also longer then the glob example:

[PHP: How can I grab a single file from a directory without scanning entire directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10642777/1456376)

Is there a very short and efficient way to solve this?

Comment: @ChrisRasco Sorting doesn't matter.

Comment: how about turning the code into a function?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Short code or efficient code?

Comment: @lampshade You said "first" which implies some type of sort. What is the basis by which you determine which file is "first"?

Comment: @MikeBrant True that - it's not worded so good. I meant like "the first you can get" - you know. Like it doesn't matter which one, just grab one. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not totally efficient, but if you only want the FIRST jpg that appears, then

```
$dh = opendir('directory/');
while($filename = readdir($dh)) {
   if (substr($filename, -4) == '.jpg')) {
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: in effect this also "does not touch all the other files"

Comment: A late +1 and thanks. Just noticed I never came back to acknowledge the effort. ;) I think this is the version that has the least overhead even though it's not a "one-liner".

Answer (score 2):

Well this is not totally a one-liner, but it is a way to go I believe:

```
$result = null;
foreach(new FilesystemIterator('directory/') as $file)
{
    if($file->isFile() && $file->getExtension() == 'jpg') {
        $result = $file->getPathname();
        break;
    }        
}
```

but why don't you wrap it in a function and use it like `get_first_file('directory/')` ? It will be a nice and short!

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for your effort. I do like the idea of using the `FilesystemIterator` as an OOP approach.

Answer (score 0):

This function will get the first filename of any type.

```
function get_first_filename ($dir) {
  $d = dir($dir);
  while ($f = $d->read()){
    if (is_file($dir . '/' . $f)) { 
      $d->close();
      return $f;
    }
  }
}
```